# Managing the same smart contract on the multiple networks by using Hardhat

Tags: hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I'm going to manage a contract on different Ethereum based networks (such as Ethereum, BSC, polygon etc.)
The behavior of the contract has some minor differences regarding the network, so I decided to deploy multiple contracts with the same name.

I used hardhat/waffle to write tests and the typechain plugin to generate TypeScript bindings.

It seems neither hardhat nor typechain doesn't support the same contract name in different files.
Typechain generates typescript declaration files only for one contract and ignore others.

Is there any way to support multiple contracts with the same name?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately no, finally I put the network name at the end of the contract name. :(

Comment: Ok, thanks for the feedback ! This was also my workaround, but it's unconvenient